# Where is the .exe when you compile in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exe

I've been doing a lil program with visual studio. So far each time I debug a .exe is created in the mainfolder/debug/. But since today in that folder I find a lot of logs and a manifest and other things, but no .exe. My program still debugs correctly. What can I do?

Comment: The output folder is specified in the project settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to:

Properties->yourprojectname properties->Configuration properties->General->Output Directory

Put a full folder name like: `C:\Users\dell\Desktop\myfolderproject\bin\debug`

There will appear your exe after debugging or compiling